# Regexp of password in WS-Security header

Tags: regex

I'm struggling with a regular expression, I'm trying to mask out a WS-Security header password.

For example:

```
<o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">jkashdajshdk&r5hdk</o:Password>
<Password>3345dgftg34</Password>
<password>3345dgftg34</password>
```

I'm looking for a expression who can handle the different styles like above.. Case insensitive, with and without type definitions etc.

Comment: what about this one <(o:)?Password[^>]*>([^<]+?)</(o:)?Password>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use group 1 from this regex:

```
<(?:o:)?password[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/(?:o:)?password>
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/4mL0uQ0ffq) of this regex working with your sample input.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:
`<(o:)?Password.*?>.+?<\/(o:)?Password>`

Requires the case insensitive setting. Alternatively `<(o:)?(P|p)assword.*?>.+?<\/(o:)?(P|p)assword>` if you don't want to use the setting, but "assword" in your code is never a pretty thing to see ;)